# How to increase the size of the check boxes in Mac Book Air /safari browser?

Tags: ios, css, macos, safari

Is it possible to increase the size of the check boxes in the Mac Book Air(Mac OS)/Safari browser,I have worked around this code :

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(1.4); /* Opera */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The above code works fine in all the browsers and also in the  windows(safari),ipad(safari) browsers.But coming to the Mac Book (Mac OS) the checkbox size remains same.
Is there is any to fix this issue in Mac OS?Please help me out with this?

Many thanks in advance.....

Comment: Input elements are inline not block level elements, and webkit has historically not supported transforms on inline elements.

One way to fix this is to add a display: inline-block to the input's CSS. I'm not an a Mac right now, so can't check this. Check it out, and let me know the results...

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor, it is working for me but the thing is i need to target only safari browser but not the chrome browser.Is their any css to target the safari browser

Comment: Yes there is, you've gotta override....